# String Representation of Map

Tags: python

**The question: How do I return a string representation of the map in the following format: {k1:v1, k2:v2, ..., kN:vN}?? Basically how do I define __repr__?**

Would I do: format = {k1:v1, k2:v2, ..., kN:vN}
strForm = str(form)
print(strForm)??

Handout:

- A map is a container for storing a collection of data records in
  which each record is associated with a unique key. The key components
  must be comparable. • Map(): Creates a new empty map. • length():
  Returns the number of key/value pairs in the map. • contains(key):
  Returns a Boolean indicating if the given key is in the map. •
  setitem(key, value): Adds a new key/value pair to the map if the key
  is not in the map. If the key is in the map, the new value replaces
  the original value associated with the key. • getitem(key): Returns
  the value associated with the given key, which must exist. • clear():
  Clears or empties the map by removing all key/value pairs. • keys():
  Returns a list containing the keys stored in the map. • values():
  Returns a list containing the values stored in the map. • toString():
  Returns a string representation of the map in the following format:
  {k1:v1, k2:v2, ..., kN:vN}

My Code (tested and runs well):

```
class Map :

def __init__( self) :
    self._key = list()
    self._value = list()

def __len__( self, key) :
    return len(self._key)

def __contains__( self, key) :
    if key in self._key :
        return True
    else:
        return False

def __setitem__( self, key, value) :
    if key in self._key :
        pos = self._key.index(key)
        self._value[pos] = value
    else :
        self._key.append(key)
        self._value.append(value)

def __getitem__( self, key) :
    assert key in self._key
    keypos = self._key.index(key)
    return self._value[keypos]

def clear( self) :
    self._key = list()
    self._value = list()
    return 

def keys( self) :
    return self._key

def values( self ) :
    return self._value

def __repr__( self ):
```

Comment: key should be a set, not list. The biggest benefit of map is fast finding of elements by key.

Comment: Are you just asking how to define `__repr__` ?

Comment: Professor prefers using a list

Comment: @user3467349 yes i am

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't subclassing a collections object?

Comment: No. I will attach what I am supossed to do.

Comment: I don't know if it's the assignment in itself not being well worded, but your solution will run in O(n) lookup, which defeats the purpose of a key-value store.

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to invent everything from a dictionary for yourself I would write the `__repr__` method the following way

```
"{%s}" % (", ".join(["%s:%s" % (k,v) for k, v in zip(self._key, self._value)]))
```

Comment: I think this `"{%s}" % ` is not needed.

Comment: @Marcin It's to add the `{` and `}`

Comment: Generally the `__init__` method should be capable of taking the `__repr__` as an argument no? He's better of subclassing an existing class like `collections.mutablemapping` and writing an `__init__` that fills his requirements.

Comment: @halex I see. So its good.

Comment: I might want to over-ride `__str__` rather that `__repr__` in order to fulfill the guideline that `__repr_`_ return a representation suitable for instantiating a copy of the instance.  Or, as user346739 says, create a subclass and over-ride `__init__` to parse the custom `__repr__`.  (I'm well aware that the guideline is not universally observed).

Answer (score 1):

I would override `__str__` or `__repr__` like the following:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return '{%s}' % ', '.join(['{}:{}'.format(k, v) for k, v in zip(self._key, self._value)])
```